# Sort 2D vector by Multiple columns

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, multiple-columns, 2d-vector

I'm using the following boost algorithm to sort my 2D vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;


class StringListCompare
{
public:
  explicit StringListCompare(int column) : m_column(column) {}
  bool operator()(const vector<string>& lhs, const vector<string>& rhs)
  {
    // what do we do if lhs or rhs don't have (m_column + 1) elements?
    return lhs[m_column] < rhs[m_column];
  }
private:
  int m_column;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector <std::vector <std::string> > data;
  std::vector <std::string> temp;
  //
  // Load 2D vector 
  sort(data.begin(), data.end(), StringListCompare(2));

  //Print 2D vector after sorting by 2nd column
}
```

Here I can sort the vector by Only one column which i specified as argument. But I want to sort this vector by two columns. My first column should be in sorted. According the first column sort I want to sort the vector again by 2nd column. 
How can i do this ?

I want to sort first by the first column, and then sort the ones with equal first column to be sorted by the second column?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to sort first by the first column, and then sort the ones with equal first column to be sorted by the second column?

Answer (score 1):

If i got what you want, lexigraphical sort (and [`std::lexigraphical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) predicate) would help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to is as @distantTransformer say a [lexicographical_compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/). It behaves almost like the `StringListCompare` that you have made, with the exception that it will go through the whole list of strings. You sort lists of strings not letters like the most common use case, but that doesn't matter for [lexicographical_compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/) as it works with iterators.

If you as a *learning experience* rather want to do the comparison yourself, and expand your StringListCompare you can do it like this:

```
bool operator()(const vector<string>& lhs, const vector<string>& rhs)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < lhs.size(); ++i) {         
     if (rhs.size() <= i) return false; //rhs has fewer strings than lhs
     if (lhs[i] < rhs[i]) return true;
     if (lhs[i] > rhs[i]) return false;
     //for loop continues while the two vectors are equal
   }
   return true; //rhs must be equal or a have more strings than lhs
}
```

You could consider rewriting this using iterators, but this is a basic implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. daramarak. But its sorting by two adjacent columns. But I want to sort by first column and equal elements will be sorted by third column or any number of column. The Secondary column should be passed as parameter. I need to take decision to sort the table by which columns. And I didn't check the above code for Date type fields. Will it be work for Date type fields ? Sorry. I need to check it . And if it is not, Please How can I change the above function to do the two operations which i mentioned.

Comment: @SmithDwayne this function will sort by any number of columns. It will first sort by the first column, if they are equal it will compare the 2nd column, then the 3rd and so on. As for sorting columns of dates the algorithm will work for dates if the dates have a operator less (operator < ) although it is currently only handling vectors of strings, not dates.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it for number. But I know this is type mismatch error.

```
class StringListCompare
{

public:
  explicit StringListCompare(int column, int column2, string fCol, string sCol) : m_column(column), m_column2(column2) , fColType(fCol), sColType(sCol) {}

  bool operator()(const vector<string>& lhs, const vector<string>& rhs)
  {

        if (lhs[m_column] == rhs[m_column])
        {
             if (fColType.compare("string")==0)
                return lhs[m_column2] < rhs[m_column2];
            else  if (fColType.compare("number")==0)
                return atoi(lhs[m_column2]) < atoi(rhs[m_column2]);
        }

        else
        {
             if (fColType.compare("string")==0)
                return lhs[m_column] < rhs[m_column];
            else  if (fColType.compare("number")==0)
                return atoi(lhs[m_column]) < atoi(rhs[m_column]);
        }

  }
private:
  int m_column;
  int m_column2;
  string fColType;
  string sColType;
};
```

Is there any logic available to do like this for different data type sorting?